# What kind of things I could "see" with an amateur radio telescope?

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing, radio-astronomy

There are apparently not many reasonably priced radio telescopes available for the amateur users. I only could find [a SPIDER 230C 2.3 meter diameter compact radio telescope](http://www.primalucelab.com/radioastronomy/spider230-amateur-radio-telescope.html), which costs ~10 k€. Reading the page, I don't get a good overview what kind of things I could "see" with a radio telescope that has a 2.3 meter antenna.

Is the instrument already a (semi-)professional one?

Comment: Related question with very insightful answer: [How big a dish do I need for radio astronomy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/21833/37191)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rather than looking for ready-made systems, take a look at projects. Right now, plenty of amateurs are using software defined radio coupled to various antennas for astronomy. Start here:

http://www.rtl-sdr.com/rtl-sdr-for-budget-radio-astronomy/

And while it has nothing to do with imaging, there's plenty of radio astronomy that amateurs can do using simple (albeit sometimes large) antennas:

- http://radiojove.gsfc.nasa.gov/
- http://radio-astronomy.org/pdf/qex/radio-jove-proof.pdf
- http://www.radiosky.com/project.html

Comment: There is a Mexican radio-astronomer with a podcast who contributed to the 365 Days of Astronomy podcast.  He did discuss building one's own.  I can't remember his name, but his podcast (or perhaps the one from Green Bank) might be very interesting to the OP.

Answer (score 5):

From my simplistic analysis, it's not good for much.

For comparison, the first [radio telescope](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_telescope) was 9 meters.

One of the favorite parts of the spectrum for radio telescopes is the water hole - 21 cm.

From my quick mental arithmetic, this dish would be able to [resolve](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_resolution) sources of 21 cm signals of they were about 5 degrees apart.