# Is it possible to make (or buy kit) DIY portable radio telescope that I can place on the balcony like optical telescope?

Tags: radio-astronomy, radio-telescope, diy

I want to have a small radio telescope to use on balcony instead of optical when sky is cloudy (it is very often).

Is it possible? What objects can be observed by that telescope? Is it possible to use 2D matrix as receiver like an astrocamera in optical telescope (to observe a sky field like optical telescopes, not a single point)?

Comment: you can check the related questions and answers here to get an idea of how difficult this would be, and then perhaps narrow down your question https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=amateur+radio See also [What kind of things I could "see" with an amateur radio telescope?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/10878/7982)

Comment: There is this: https://radiojove.gsfc.nasa.gov/gettingstarted/

Comment: Consider the size of the dish you'd need (wavelength-related) compared with optical scopes.   Compare with, e.g.,  satellite TV receiver dishes and the wavelengths at which they operate.   Next, think about how you are going to produce an **image**

Comment: Speaking of tv dishes: https://hackaday.com/2019/10/22/a-miniature-radio-telescope-in-every-backyard/ . Probably possible to operate on a balcony but to set expectations you will probably be very underwhelmed by the output.

Comment: Recommend focusing this question on a single topic as the three questions here presently make this overly broad and difficult to answer this forum.